# Is there a definitive guide/walkthrough out there on upgrading from EE 1.12.0.0 to EE 1.13.1.10

Tags: upgrade, ee-1.13, ee-1.12

I have been looking around for a couple days now and I have not been able to find a guide that encapsulates the whole process of upgrading from version 1.12.0.0 to 1.13.1.10.

I was wondering if anyone here knew if a guide like that existed somewhere.

Note: I know of the guide on Magento's page, http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee11302-ce18-install-upgrade,
but I am looking of a different one if it exists.

Comment: Oops, I mean 1.13.1.0, not 1.13.1.10.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to migrate your Magento from One machine to another, the basic steps you need to follow are:

Move your Magento files from source to destination server
from phpMyAdmin, export your magento database as a SQL file, save that file and move it to new server in any location
in your new server, delete app\etc\local.xml file
from your new server's phpMyAdmin, create a database and import the SQL file you've imported from old server
now from your browser, open the magento root directory path in new server, install magento with all credentials
Note: after installation all the data and designs will be there as like previous server magento

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for something on upgrading Magento versions, not migrating from one machine to another.

Comment: Hello Ronak, if you want to upgrade with the same installation, then just upgrade the existing files with new ones. But it's better practise to make a new staging location and upgrade your current database with new Enterprise files as per above mentioned process.